# getActionView from MenuItem returns null if wrong order

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, menuitem

As the title says, I can't figure it out. I'm NOT using compat support library. Using `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`
This is my action_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_search"/>

</menu>
```

This is my activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
        mi = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        search = (SearchView)mi.getActionView();
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(getOnQueryTextListener());
        new SearchTask().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("query"));
        return true;
    }
```

`mi` is a MenuItem. `search` is a SearchView. 
If the order of declaration of the items in action_menu.xml is as written, getActionView returns null.
If the order is inverted, it works. Why?

Comment: Check : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsageofSearchViewinanActionBarasamenuitem.htm

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="@string/action_search"/>

</menu>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Why should it work? When i try it says "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionViewClass' in package 
  'it.myapp'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 
  'it.myapp'"

Comment: Pedro Oliveira is right. I know that the namespace should be changed to a custom one when using support library.